# What function should I use in instead of mimemail()?

Tags: 7, mimemail

I was using `mimemail()`, a function defined from the MIME mail module, in Drupal 6 to send emails using attachments.

The Drupal 7 module doesn't have `mimemail()`.

What function should I use in Drupal 7, instead of `mimemail()`?

Answer (score 3):

The reason the `mimemail()` function does not exist for Drupal 7 is because it is not needed.

See, for instance, issue: [API function for quick send html mail without uneccessary operations (mimemail analog from 6.x)](https://drupal.org/node/1512008#comment-8884679) in the project's issue queue;

> On Drupal 7 calling `drupal_mail()` is enough. See the [`README.txt`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mimemail/tree/README.txt) and [`drupal_mail_system()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system/7) for more information.

The general idea is that you set up the Drupal to use `MimeMailSystem` for some or all mail messages sent by your module:

```
mailsystem_set(array(
  '{$module}_{$key}' => 'MimeMailSystem', // Just messages with $key sent by $module.
  '{$module}' => 'MimeMailSystem', // All messages sent by $module.
));
```

and then calling `drupal_mail()` is enough.